# PNG disappears when exporting/printing map in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-9.3, png

Ive added a PNG image of a chart to my map and when i try to export as any image file or print the map the PNG image is not there.  Im using arcmap 9.3. in layout view im adding image which ive tried as a jpg and png. it appears on the layout itself but once i print or export the map the image is no longer visible on the printout or export. Also, the image does not appear on the print preview. Ive added image files to many of my maps before so im not sure what would be causing this

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the complete answer, but there seems to be a problem with GIF and PNG images that have transparent backgrounds not displaying or export/printing correctly in ArcGIS v9.x - 10
Here is the Knowledge Base Article:  [Transparent GIF and PNG inserted images do not display and/or do not export or print as transparent](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34286)

It is not really clear from the article if the entire image will not export properly, or just the transparent area.  In some cases, what is supposed to be transparent shows up as black or some other color.  I think your issue may be related to this if you happen to have a transparent background set on your chart.

If possible, I would try exporting the chart as an EMF graphic or remove the transparency on the background, as suggested in the article.

Comment: I tried to alter the original Image file and filled in the background and again had no luck with the image appearing on an export or print out even as a EMF graphic.  Then instead of adding the image via Insert>image i added it via add data and put it in a new data frame and it ended up working out.  Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

It's been 10 years since the question asked, but I'm gonna put this here in case anyone need this. I saved as the picture to TIFF and insert the image using Insert > Picture. It works.

Answer (score -1):

When I had the same problem, I grouped the "missing jpg." file with other elements that were showing after exporting, and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the image and go to properties and tick the box for save as part of document